# How to get all text from multiple files

Tags: php

I'm trying to get all of the text from diffrent text files in a certain folder using PHP. I've already figured out how to do it for all the images in a folder but now i need a way to do the same for text files. This is the code i have so far.

```
<?php
$dir = 'Nieuws';
$file_display = ['txt'];

if (file_exists($dir) == false) {
    return ["Directory \'', $dir, '\' not found!"];
} else {
    $dir_contents = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($dir_contents as $file) {
        echo $file;
        echo file_get_contents($file);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `echo file_get_contents($dir . '/'. $file);`

Comment: That would indeed work for 1 file but i want to know how to get all the files from a folder.

Comment: No, change the line in your while loop to that

Comment: And you will need some think to ignore the `.` and `..` directories